# Find fundamental matrix of homogenous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am unable to find the fundamental matrix of the associated homogeneous system below:

$$
\vec{y}^{\prime}=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
-4 & 4 \\
-8 & 4
\end{array}\right] \vec{y}+\left[\begin{array}{l}
-4 \\
-3
\end{array}\right]
$$

1. By taking $\text{det}(\lambda I - A)$ I get the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2-16= 0$, which has solutions $\pm 4i$.
2. I place said lambda values back in the system:
   **(EDIT: changed 1 + i to 1 -i as per the comment!)**
   $$
   \begin{pmatrix} 4i +4 & -4  \\  8 & 4i-4\end{pmatrix}
   $$
   This is equivalent with (divinding first row with -4, multipling by (i+1)):
   $$
   \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1-i  \\  0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
   $$
   This has solution: $c_1\left[\begin{array}{l}
   1 \\
   1+i
   \end{array}\right]e^{4i}$.
   In the same manner I get $c_2\left[\begin{array}{l}
   1 \\
   1-i
   \end{array}\right]e^{-4i}$. Seems correct since they are inverse of each other.

While converting to real numbers, I get it wrong.
I find:
$$ X_1 = 
c_1\left[\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
1
\end{array}\right]cos(4t)+  \left[\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]sin(4t)\right]
$$

$$ X_2 = 
c_2\left[\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
1
\end{array}\right]cos(-4t) -  \left[\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
-1
\end{array}\right]sin(-4t)\right] = c_2\left[\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
1
\end{array}\right]cos(4t) -  \left[\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]sin(4t)\right]
$$

What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes you are right, it should be (-2 , 1 - i ) on the first row I believe!

Comment: Hmm so it's not even -2?

Comment: I get 0 -->(4i +4) e^(4i) -4(1+i)e^(4i) = 0. Or ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I am not sure I understood how to calculate those complex eigenvectors!

Comment: Right. I was unsure about that. Then$$
\begin{pmatrix} -2  & 1-i \\  0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1  \\   1+i\end{pmatrix}
$$ should work as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the system

$$Y'=\begin{bmatrix}-4 & 4\\-8 & 4\end{bmatrix}Y +\begin{bmatrix}-4\\-3\end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2} = \pm 4i$.

Using $\lambda_1 = 4i$, we find the eigenvector of RREF $[A-\lambda_1I]v_1 =[A - 4iI]v_1= 0$, which leads to

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\0\end{bmatrix}$$

We choose (note, eigenvectors are not unique) $$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1-i \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$

$v_2$ is just to conjugate of that.

We can now write the solution

$$Y = c_1 e^{\lambda_1} v_1 + c_2 e^{\lambda_2} v_2 = c_1e^{4i}\begin{bmatrix}1-i \\ 2\end{bmatrix} +c_2e^{-4i}\begin{bmatrix}1+i \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, convert that first eigenvalue/eigenvector to real and create the fundamental matrix from it.

Comment: How do you convert to real? I had one wrong out of two.

Comment: Can you follow example 1: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/ComplexEigenvalues.aspx You could also use https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/matrix-methods-eigenvalues-and-normal-modes/MIT18_03SCF11_s33_7text.pdf

Comment: I actually followed the steps on Paul website, and find [cos(4t), cos(4t); cos(4t) + sin(4t), cos(4t) - sin(4t)] and I know that this fundamental matrix is incorrect. I never saw the second source you are quoting, let me give it a try tomorrow morning! It seems like a really good worked example...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help yesterday and excellent sources. 
I understand what I don't understand now :). It is the "cross multiplication" between real and imaginary parts:
$x_{1}=e^{-t}\left(\left(\begin{array}{l}0 \\ 2\end{array}\right) \cos (2 t)-i\left(\begin{array}{r}1 \\ -2\end{array}\right) \sin (2 t)\right)=e^{-t}\left(\begin{array}{c}-\sin (2 t) \\ 2 \cos (2 t)+2 \sin (2 t)\end{array}\right)$
and

Comment: and 
$x_{2}=e^{-t}\left(\left(\begin{array}{r}1 \\ -2\end{array}\right) \cos (2 t)-i\left(\begin{array}{l}0 \\ 2\end{array}\right) \sin (2 t)\right)=e^{-t}\left(\begin{array}{c}-\cos (2 t) \\ -2 \cos (2 t)+2 \sin (2 t)\end{array}\right)$

I don't get the logic between this "cross multiplication!"

Comment: Excellent! Here is a geometric explanation of why: http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/complex-eig2005.pdf

Comment: There is also a clean writeup in Boyce / DiPirma Section 3.3.